# MySQL How to select specific records in one table join (1-many) in another table where records have condition on 1 field?

Tags: mysql

I have table `"items"` and table `"offers"`, and they are joined by `i.item_id = o.item_id`.

Let's say `item_id = 1` has 2 records in offers table: one with `o.status = 0` and another with `o.status = 1`.

Then `item_id = 2` has also 2 records in offers table and both have `o.status = 0`.

How can I select only records from items where none of them have `o.status = 1`? So I need to select only record of `item_id = 2` from items table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Select offer item ids with status = 1 and filter them from items table.

```
select * from items where item_id not in (
select distinct item_id from offers where status=1)
```

Here is the [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ed316/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

A version without subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN offers ON offers.item_id = items.item_id AND offers.status = 1
WHERE offers.item_id IS NULL
```